# how to get the selected radio button value from models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm doing a website in django but this is the first time i use this framework so i'm not so used to it.
I need to save some information on a DB, and i need to take these information from some radio buttons.
I tryied so many ways to get the data but nothing worked.
So i'd like to ask how to get these data in `models.py` from  a `template,html`.

This is the code in `views.py`:

```
def question1(request):
    form = CHOICES(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'question1.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the template `question1.html`:

```
<form class="form-inline" method='POST' action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}

                {{form.NUMS}}
</form>
```

Then there is the form in `forms.py`:

```
NUMS = [
  ('one', 'one'),
  ('two', 'two'),
  ('three', 'three'),
  ('four', 'four'),
  ('five', 'fives'),
]

class CHOICES(forms.Form):
    NUMS = forms.ChoiceField(choices=NUMS, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

And then i literally don't know how to do the function in `models.py`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read through this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/

Basically you want a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) that links to your model in models.py

Then (assuming your form is called CHOICES) in your view would be like this:

```
def question1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CHOICES(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data())
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CHOICES()
    return render(request, 'question1.html', {'form': form})
```

The template would want to be like :

```
<form class="form-inline" method='POST' action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
But the problem is that I don't know how to get the selected radio button to save it on the DB

Comment: @Burzi I have edited the answer to have print(form.cleaned_data()) that print statement will print the values from the form. They will also be in the request.POST.

Comment: On print(form.cleaned_data()) i have this error:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/question1.html
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Burzi my bad added extra parenthesis.